# Unable to concatenate asterisk

Tags: crystal-reports, concatenation, asterisk

My formula concatenates an asterisk, a field, then another asterisk in prep for a code 39 barcode. I've done this a million times, including twice before on the same report. For whatever reason the output shows the first asterisk, the field value, but NOT the second asterisk. Here is the actual formula:

```
"*" & {CNTR_SCHED.PRIORITY_NOTE2} & "*"
```

I have tried several different things and I cannot get the output to display the second asterisk. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Have you checked the length of the field data to see if there may be a long string of spaces at the end that could cause the field on your report to be too narrow to display the complete value?  You could easily check this by enabling the Can Grow property on your text field.

Comment: Checked can grow, it now shows the second asterisk but on a second line?

Comment: Changed max number of lines to 1, asterisk disappears. It's acting like there is a carriage return. Never seen this before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are correct about there being a Carriage Return in the data value.  Try this formula to remove it.  I've had this problem in note fields often with Crystal Reports.

```
"*" & Replace({CNTR_SCHED.PRIORITY_NOTE2}, Chr(13), "") & "*"
```

If that doesn't work, try changing the `Chr(13)` to `Chr(10)`.

Chr(13) is the code for a Carriage Return, while Chr(10) is the code for a Line Feed.  Sometimes you may even need to do a replace for both codes, but that tends to be fairly rare in my experience.

*EDIT*

See if this formula works instead.  This one will do both replacements for Line Feed and Carriage Return.

```
"*" & Replace(Replace({CNTR_SCHED.PRIORITY_NOTE2}, Chr(10), ""), Chr(13), "") & "*"
```

Comment: Tried both "*" & Replace({CNTR_SCHED.PRIORITY_NOTE}, Chr(13), "") & "*" and "*" & Replace({CNTR_SCHED.PRIORITY_NOTE}, Chr(10), "") & "*". No luck. Can you help me with the syntax for replacing both?

Comment: This could be one of the rare cases where it need both replacements.  I will update the answer with the formula for this.

Comment: Found an example. That did it. Thank you SO much for your help! "*" & Replace(Replace({CNTR_SCHED.PRIORITY_NOTE}, Chr(10), ""),Chr(13), "") & "*"